# Laravel 8: keep modal open if there are errors

Tags: laravel, error-handling, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, laravel-8

I would like to let the modal keep open if there are errors,but the modal will not auto open when there are errors

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ url('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   

 @if($errors->any())
       <script type="text/javascript">  
            $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#modal-title').modal('show');   
            });   
     </script>              
  @endif
```

modal

```
    <form action="/employee" class="action" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-scroll" aria-labelledby="modal-title" id="modal-title" role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
            x-show="open">
```

Comment: you should use ajax for this

Comment: @Umer Fayyaz Could you please tell me how to use ajax for this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    $('#modal-title').modal('show');
@endif
</script>
```

Comment: still will not keep the modal open when there are errors

Comment: good way is to use ajax. you can find here how to use its simple https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFhnxnJ7pLU

Comment: I followed the video still failed@Umer Fayyaz

Comment: @ Umer Fayyaz  This is my code                                       
  <script>
        $('#first_name_error').addClass('d-none');
            $ajax(
                error: function(data){
                    var errors= data.responseJSON;
                    if($.isEmptyObject(errors) == false){
                        $.each(errors,function(key,value){
                            var ErrorID = '#' +key+'Error';
                            $(ErrorID).removeClass("d-none");
                            $(ErrorID).text(value)
                        })   } } )</script>